# SpringMVC URL-Mapping

Tags: spring-mvc, url-mapping

I have deployed my tomcat war succesfully on Amazon EC2 today.
On my local machine the following link: localhost:8080/login works totally fine

But on my EC2 instance, the link always has to have the .war name in the link:

http://some-amazon-link:8080/the-war-name/login

Now im struggling how and where i have to add that "/the-war-name/" in my Spring MVC project.

wether its in the

- web.xml
- the views
- the controllers.

With the code below i can access the login with the following link:
localhost:8080/login
but i want it to be
localhost:8080/some-war-name/login

I've tried adding the /some-war-name/ to the @RequestMapping, changing the dispatcher

My login.jsp:

```java
<html>
<head>
<title>Login ProV</title>
<link href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <p><font color="red">${errorMessage}</font></p>


    <form action="/login" method="POST">
       <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Benutzername</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername1" placeholder="Benutzernamen eingeben">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" />
    </form>




    <script src="webjars/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My web.xml

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>To do List</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/todo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My LoginController

```java
package com.mschm.login;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import com.mschm.login.LoginService;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("name")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    LoginService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public String showLoginPage() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public String handleLoginRequest(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String password, ModelMap model) {
        if(!service.validateUser(name, password)) {
            model.put("errorMessage", "Invalid Credentials");
            return "login";

        } else {
            model.put("name", name);
            model.put("password", password);
            return "welcome";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome! It is confusing what you want, but I think you want to add the war name on your localhost. If so add it to this line `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` in your web.xml

Comment: Hi, ok i try to explain it with my localhost link again,
right now with the code shown above i can access my login.jsp with "/login":

localhost:8080/login
what do i have to change, to access the link with the following url:
localhost:8080/foobar/login

Comment: If you change `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/foobar</url-pattern>` you should get that.

Comment: sadly when i do that, I get a 404 error.:

HTTP Status 404 - /foobar/login
type Status report

message /foobar/login

description The requested resource is not available.
Do i also have to change the directory to WEB-INF/views/foobar?

Answer (score 0):

> that "/the-war-name/"

is called the `context path` for your application.

You need to configure `tomcat` to use an empty context path in your case. **There are several ways** to achieve this.

One of them is to add following to `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml`:

```
<Host name="your.host.name" >
   <Context path="" docBase="/path/to/the-war-name.war"/>
</Host>
```

### **Further Reading:**

[***Defining a context*** in *Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference*.](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context)